# Adding Multiple Graphs in 1 svg without overlapping in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using d3 line chart with zooming and brush features, to plot the behavior of 2 different processes, what happens is that both graphs overlap. How can I change the code to avoid overlapping.

My data structure is like,

```
{
    "processes": [{
            "calls": [{
                    "val": "A",
                    "id": 0
                },
                {
                    "val": "B",
                    "id": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "calls": [{
                    "val": "B",
                    "id": 0
                },
                {
                    "val": "B",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "val": "C",
                    "id": 2
                },
                {
                    "val": "A",
                    "id": 3
                },
                {
                    "val": "B",
                    "id": 4
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am following the code mentioned in the link below

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 and also adding the image for clarity[image]

Comment: You can use different stroke color and styles for each processes.

Comment: But i want separate chart/graph for every process, not multi-line chart.i.e, every process must have its own brush, axis, etc